# Remove part of the URI, then pass to script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently my `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA]
```

All URIs are passed to the PHP script which then parses it and returns stuff.

Now I want to implement a versioning system, in which there would be different script handling the URIs depending on the version called.

That is:

- if I call `/v1/countries/es/users`, I want to pass the URI `/countries/es/users` to the script `v1.php`
- if I call `/v2/users/314/settings`, then I want the URI `/users/314/settings` passed to the script `v2.php`

I tried doing something like

```
RewriteRule ^/?v(\d)/.*$ v$1.php [QSA]
```

That would send execution to the version-specific script, but I still want to strip out the `/v1/` initial part of the URI when passed to the script, i.e., **I want the script to receive the URI without the initial version part**.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It clearly explains in [apache document: Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

You could pass it as parameter, and use `$_GET['route']` to get the URI part without first version part:

```
RewriteRule ^/v(\d)/(.*)$ v$1.php?param1=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/v(\d)/(.*)/(.*)$ v$1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This would put the whole of the path inside a query parameter. It looks rather simple, but I would like to know if there is a solution in which the URI path is retrieved as the URI path rather than as a query parameter.

Comment: you could write your own router using php, parsing URL, `parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`